# Не срабатывает анимация

Tags: android

Всем привет, буду очень благодарен, если поможете.

Есть `ViewGroup` с набором `TextView`.
В каждый момент мы видим один `TextView`, можем прокручивать влево или вправо, чтобы увидеть другие, для этого использую [`RealViewSwitcher`](http://marcreichelt.blogspot.ru/2010/09/android-use-realviewswitcher-to-switch.html).

Хочу сделать крутилку бесконечной, для этого при достижении последнего элемента, беру первый, удаляю и добавляю в конец.

```
 //Получаем первый элемент
 TextView textView2 = (TextView)this.getChildAt(0);
 //Добавляем в конец
 this.addView(textView4);
 //Прокурчиваем             
 snapToScreen(mCurrentScreen + 1);
 //Удаляем первый           
 this.removeView(this.getChildAt(0));
```

Все срабатывает, но из-за `removeView` не срабатывает анимация. Экран просто резко меняется. В андроиде новичок. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так она и не будет срабатывать.

Предположу.

Вы ставите анимацию на вьюху и удаляете ее потом. Попробуйте сделать анимацию для всего контейнера или в виде диаложка над контролом.

Также, советую использовать [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) для листания между вьюхами плавно и быстро вместо подобной самописной шелухи.

Comment: Буду разбираться, огромное спасибо за потраченное время и совет.